# Strictly convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

When a function is strictly convex it has many desirable properties, most notably that it admits a unique minimum.

I was wondering if there is anything desirable about a *strictly convex set* (meaning that for any two points, all points between lie strictly within the set)? In the problems I've seen, most only care to distinguish between the convexity and non-convexity of a set and leave it at that. Does anyone know of any applications where *strict* convexity of a set is taken advantage of?

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of main properties of strictly convex set is uniqueness of minimum (or maximum) of any linear functional on it.

Comment: I'm late to the party here but $f(x)\equiv 0$ will not have a unique minimum on any set with more than one point.

Comment: Any none zero linear functional ... .Thanks to @MichaelGrant.